# 'does not have member' when calling objective C setter method from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, getter-setter

After importing the objective C robbiehanson/XMPPFramework into a swift project (setting up build setting, bridging header, etc).  I am able to call normal methods in the imported classes and set properties directly.

However, certain instance methods that set properties cause immediate errors as if they don't exist in the instances I'm calling them on.  For example:

```
- (void)setMyJID:(XMPPJID *)newMyJID
{
    [self setMyJID_setByClient:newMyJID];
}
```

Or even the `setMyJID_setByClient:newMyJID` method which actually does the setting.

In two separate objective c example projects I have looked at, the setMyJID method is being called from other classes. However, while I am able to call other instance methods on the class, I can't call this one. Since I am not very familiar with objective c, I though this might be because it wasn't declared in the header file, causing some swift specific problem, but attempts to add a declaration for it did not help.

I am able to set the relevant property directly, but this is not only undesirable, I also would like to understand why I am not able to call certain methods.

I am attempting to make the call on an instance of the XMPPStream class like this

```
    //This shows immediate error: XMPPStream does not have a member named 'setMyJID'
    stream.setMyJID(XMPPJID.jidWithString(someXMPPAddress)
    // This works perfectly
    stream.myJID = (XMPPJID.jidWithString(someXMPPAddress))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`XMPPStream`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Core/XMPPStream.h) class, `myJID` is declared as follows:

```
@property (readwrite, copy) XMPPJID *myJID;
```

In Objective-C, this means that there are actually two methods on the `XMPPStream` class that conform to the following signatures:

```
- (XMPPJID *)myJID;
- (void)setMyJID:(XMPPJID *)myJID;
```

So, from Objective-C code, you can call them like any other method. However, as you know, you also have the option of using the syntactic sugar in the language known as "dot notation":

```
// getter with dot notation
XMPPJID *jid = stream.myJID;
// setter with dot notation
stream.myJID = jid;
```

However, in Objective-C, these dot notation expressions are *directly translated* into calls to the getter and setter. They're just there to look nice.

Things are different in Swift. When you have a property, like this one:

```
var myJID: XMPPJID
```

this *does not* mean that there exist separate getter and setter methods, like you might be imagining:

```
func myJID() -> XMPPJID {}
func setMyJID(jid: XMPPJID) {}
```

In Swift, you must access properties using dot syntax.

Knowing this, your problem becomes obvious. When you tried:

```
stream.setMyJID(XMPPJID.jidWithString(someXMPPAddress)
```

Swift tried to run the instance method `setMyJID` of `stream`, and found, rightly, that it did not exist! This, of course:

```
stream.myJID = (XMPPJID.jidWithString(someXMPPAddress))
```

works perfectly, because you're setting a property as Swift requires.

---

As an educational aside, you may sometimes see cases where, when accessing Objective-C properties from Swift, you not only can, but *must* use the getter and setter methods - dot notation won't even work! This seems totally counterintuitive, but there's a good reason for why this happens. One example of this that I can think of off the top of my head is the verbosely-named `UIView` property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, used for view layout. If you try to use it in Swift, like so:

```
// Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false on self
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

you would get a compilation error! Specifically,

> Cannot assign to 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' in 'self'

Why? The answer lies in the `UIView` headers:

```
- (BOOL)translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // Default YES
- (void)setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:(BOOL)flag NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

It turns out that this "property," like many others in the Cocoa frameworks, is actually just a pair of methods that *look* like property accessors. Because of how Objective-C translates dot notation into method calls, you'd never notice before. Now, though, Swift is stricter – to get and set this "property," you must call the appropriate methods.